# Keras cant predict with the same image shape as in the training

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

I have made a DNN for hand pose detection (rgb image to float). The input of my model is (640, 480, 3) and the images are in numpy shape (480, 640, 3) and I don't know how I trained that. But the problem is that when I do the same when predicting, I get this error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer model: expected shape=(None, 640, 480, 3), found shape=(32, 640, 3)
```

Here the code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

model = load_model(models_path + '1.h5')

TestGenerator = DataGenerator(path, partition['test'], batch_size=16)

print(TestGenerator[0][0][0].shape)

x = TestGenerator[0][0][0]

y = model.predict(x)
```

Comment: You need to reshape to the size `(number_of_samples, width, height, channel)`, i.e. (1, 640, 480, 3)

Comment: Your test image has height 32

Comment: Check the shape of the test images.